# Change the artifact name while uploading to Maven Repository through command line

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I am new to Maven and looking out for ways to upload many 'XML'(not jars) files to a Maven Repository.

I came across the 'mvn deploy' command which allows me to successfully upload the files to a Maven Nexus Repository. 
I am using below command to upload single file successfully. So my XML gets uploaded with name com/xxx/test/test/0.1/test-0.1.xml.

```
call mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.xxx.test -DartifactId=test -Dversion=0.1 -DgeneratePom=false -DrepositoryId=kepler-releases -Durl=http://example.com:8081/repository/xxx-release -Dfile=xxx/abc.xml
```

Is there a way that I can upload multiple xml files under this same group 'com.xxx.test' with their existing file names (like abc.xml in this case)?

I saw there is some option -finalName but couldnt find many examples around its use. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you uploading xml files to your Maven repository? Usually, one would bundle the files to a zip and upload the zip.

Comment: You got it right. I missed to update the answer but I did the same way. Packaged all xmls into a zip and uploaded the same to maven nexus repo.